# AChartEngine localised lables android

Tags: android, achartengine

I am creating an adroid app and I am using AChartEngine to create some charts. I am using `TimeChart` to create a graph. Everything is working fine but I cannot get the labels in Y axis to change format. So instead of the values being shown like 2000.12 I want them to show like 2.000,12. If I could pass `Strings` and not `doubles` I could easily format it. Is there a way to do that without having to use `addYTextLabel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
mRenderer.setLabelFormat(nf);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rendererChart.addXTextLabel(timeSeriesChart.getY(0),
"your new formatted string");
```

where 
rendererChart is an instance of XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.

timeSeriesChart is an instance of TimeSeries.

This will change the label of the first marker on the Y axis to your custom label.

Comment: I want to avoid that so that I can use mRenderer.setYLabels(value). I don't want to add them manually. Thats why I wrote: Is there a way to do that without having to use addYTextLabel